# twig dynamic key in array

Tags: symfony, twig

I am bussy with a Twig template and had the following problem. I have a array with certain values:

```
 'ideal' => 
      array
  0 => string '62014' (length=5)
  1 => string '62014' (length=5)
  2 => string '62014' (length=5)
  3 => string '62014' (length=5)
  4 => string '62014' (length=5)
  5 => string '62014' (length=5)
  6 => string '62014' (length=5)
  7 => string '62014' (length=5)
  8 => string '62014' (length=5)
  9 => string '62014' (length=5)
  10 => string '62014' (length=5)
  11 => string '62014' (length=5)
```

Now i have the following code to loop trough the keys

```
  {% for key in stats|keys %}
                var key = key;
                stats.push('{{ key }}');
```

So first i want to get the key and when i have the key i want to use the key to get the values in that key so 62014 0 to 11.

```
 {% for key,value in stats['ideal']%}
                    stats2.push('{{ value.key}}');
                {% endfor %}
```

tried it this way. so i want to get the values in the dynamic key. How should i handle that.

complete code:

```
 {% for key in stats|keys %}
                var key = key;
                stats.push('{{ key }}');
                {% for key,value in stats['ideal']%}
                    stats2.push('{{ value.key}}');
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense... at least not to me anyway.

Comment: for me too ... i read two times and don't understand ...

Comment: Please refine your question if you would like to get an anwser. It seems you're mixing twig/js variables together which will never work... What did you expect when you did `var key = key`?